# How can I step into others source-code when debugging with eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I downloaded the source-code to my application container (Tomcat, if that matters), and now want to make eclipse show that where appropriate when debugging.

How do I make eclipse aware of those sources?

Comment: I would just create a new project in Eclipse and set its source directory to the Tomcat source.  Have you tried it and it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

During debugging, when you step into a Tomcat's class, Eclipse would show you the compiled class along with the message `Source not found` and a neat button that says `Attach Source...`. Use that button and browse for your downloaded official Tomcat source code.

Here's a snapshot of some other 3rd party I used without having the source code at hand that resulted the mentioned message:

[image]

Comment: thx for the answer, but I like to modify code and see how it works which your option does not allow.

Comment: @sotn so you have to download the source code... You can use Maven plugin (built-in for new versions of Eclipse) in order to download it.

Answer (score -1):

First, download the souce code zip file (for example `apache-tomcat-7.0.67.zip`) from the official Tomcat website. Keep it wherever you want.

Then, highlight any predefined tomcat class of your code in Eclipse by double clicking on class then pressing F2. You will get a message showing with the symbol' @ ' saying that the class doesn't have any source attached. Click on that, then click on 'attach source' and then 'external source' and locate your downloaded source code of tomcat zip file. In this way you can attach any source code in Eclipse.

Comment: The lack of format and punctuation make your answer nearly impossible to understand (and could be the reason for the downvote).